# What is the plugin to import image from URL?

Tags: images, gallery, import

How can i import image from specific URL to image gallery in Wordpress so that i can use it as a thumbnail for post? I search for a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

These plugins, by their description, appear to do what you want.

- [Cache Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cache-images/) (by Matt Mullenweg—if I were you, I'd try this first)
- [Add Linked Images To Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-linked-images-to-gallery-v01/)
- [Hot Linked Image Cacher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hot-linked-image-cacher/)

But looking at the support forums, it's apparent that the plugins work for some and don't for others (probably due to some incompatibilities).

So, you'd be better off if you...

1. backup your WHOLE site — database, images — everything, before trying the plugin(s).
2. Make sure the `uploads` directory has proper permissions (755)`